# How to upload, replace and delete multiple images to react-final-form

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-final-form, react-final-form-arrays

I want to create, replace and delete 3 images within a form. I'm using `react-final-form` and just wondered how I would do this? I can get three file inputs on the page but figure out how to update each file in the array or delete them.

I would like my initial values to be something this:

```
{
  images: [{}, {}, {}]
}
```

Then upload one image

```
{
  images: [File, {}, {}]
}
```